# Vite sends internal server error: Unable to parse {"file":"translation.html","line":39,"column":1}

Tags: javascript, vite

I cloned and ran a vite server:
https://github.com/fireship-io/webrtc-firebase-demo

I followed the instructions and ran

```
npm run dev
```

I created 2 new html files and linked them using  tags
I can access the first file otherfile.html without issue, but when clicking on the second link, I get

```
[vite] Internal server error: Unable to parse {"file":"translation.html","line":39,"column":1}
 at traverseHtml (D:\WebRTC\webrtc-firebase-demo\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-e0f09032.js:23067:15)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async devHtmlHook (D:\WebRTC\webrtc-firebase-demo\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-e0f09032.js:61779:5)
      at async applyHtmlTransforms (D:\WebRTC\webrtc-firebase-demo\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-e0f09032.js:23333:21)
      at async D:\WebRTC\webrtc-firebase-demo\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-e0f09032.js:61841:28
```

File Structure:

```
webrtc-firebase-demo\
      |
      |__ index.html
      |__ main.js
      |__ translation.html
      |__ otherfile.html
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="videos">
      <span>
        <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 90vw; margin: 0 auto">
      <video id="webcamVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
      <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto;">
        <button id="webcamButton">Start webcam</button>
        <button id="callButton" disabled>Create Call (offer)</button>
        <button id="answerButton" disabled>Answer</button>
        <button id="hangupButton" disabled>Hangup</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="otherfile.html">Otherfile</a>
    <a href="translation.html">Translation</a>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

translation.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>JavaScript Speech to Text</title>
    <script src="\translation.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Translation</p>
    <div style="margin: 0 0 0 41vw;">
        <label for="inputlanguage">Select Language</label>
        <select name="inputlanguage" id="inputlang">
            <option value="english">english</option>
            <option value="chinese">chinese</option>
            <option value="tamil">tamil</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin: 0 0 0 20vw">
        <textarea style="width:50vw; height: 50vh; font-size: 4vh;" id="input"></textarea>
        <img src="img/download.png" onclick="runSpeechRecognition()" style="float: left;" id="action">
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0 0 0 41vw;">
        <label for="outputlanguage">Select Language</label>
        <select name="outputlanguage" id="outputlang">
            <option value="english">english</option>
            <option value="chinese">chinese</option>
            <option value="tamil">tamil</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin: 0 0 0 20vw">
        <textarea style="width:50vw; height: 50vh; font-size: 4vh;" id="output"></textarea>
        <img src="img/download (1).png" onclick="saytext()" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Clicking on the link causes a 500 internal server error

Comment: Please share a [mcve] specifically the translation.html file?

Comment: The problem is visibly in `translation.html`, which you didn't provide

Comment: Hi I have added both

Answer (score 0):

On **translation.html**, try adding the openning tag of html after <!doctype html> so it looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).